# React Native build - How to enable debug menu (shake) in release

Tags: react-native

How to enable debug menu (by shaking device) in Release build in React Native development?
(I am not using Expo)

Answer (score 2):

So the fact that you cannot do this on release is not exactly true. You could do something like this

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
...
onMenuButtonClick(){
 NativeModules.DevMenu.show();
}
```

Good practice is to only add the button on DEV but technically you can add this on release as well.

There are other ways of doing this but they are a little more complicated and may not work on both platforms. I cannot current test this but this used to work on both platforms and its pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can not enable the debug menu in release (production) builds.
Please refer below for more details: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging