# Enable React Native Developer Menu in Release

Tags: react-native

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277344/react-native-build-how-to-enable-debug-menu-shake-in-release) does not work in reality. It seems that `NativeModules.DevMenu.show()` is not working in the release build. Any lead on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The React Native Developer Menu will not work in the release mode, because of the following line of code in this [file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/466ba91657360cad57ebd67620753ab4dca29f8d/Libraries/Utilities/DevSettings.js) in the react-native source code :

```
if (__DEV__)
```

This checks if you're in development mode, then it emits the event for dev menu. The codes are of course added into the release.

If you really do want to use in release mode, then you can fork the react-native repo and patch this line and use your own personal copy of react-native.

Comment: No, you cannot modify this

Comment: The only way is to patch it in your own copy